# signalR global hub start connection in a view and use it in a partial view MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have start a connection with hub in a view and make it global for use the some connection in a partial view.
But in a partial view the method is connection from hub and send the message, but is not received in other cliente.
When I tired global variable and start again the hub connection in partial view, the messages have arrived as well.

what's wrong in global start connection variable use?

In hub I have:

```
    public void SendQuestionario(int id, string message, string userNameTo)
    {

        UserConnection connect = usersConnect.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionID == userNameTo);

        if (connect != null)
        {

            Clients.User(connect.UserName).addNewMessageToPageQuestionario(id, message);


        }
```

In a view:

```
$(function () {

    window.chat = $.connection.chatHub;


    chat.client.notificacaoIAD = function (message) {

        alert(message);

    };


    chat.client.updateStatus = function (message) {

        alert(message);

        if (message == "Online") {
            $("#status").text("Online")
        }
        else
            $("#status").text("Offline")

    };




window.hubReady=$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

        alert("Connection succeeded");


        //verificar o status do user para a ligação
        chat.server.verificaStatus(userFrom, userTo);


    }).fail(function () {

        alert("Connection failed");

    });

});
```

In partial view:

$(function () {

```
//var chat = $.connection.chatHub;


    window.chat.client.addNewMessageToPageQuestionario = function (id, message) {

        alert(message);

        $("#responder_" + id).append(htmlEncode(message));
        //$("#content_" + id).html(message);
    };




window.hubReady.done(function () {


        $(".sendmessage").click(function () {


            var id = $(this).attr('id');


            alert($("#resposta_" + id).val());


            window.chat.server.sendQuestionario(id, ($("#resposta_" + id).val()), nome);

            });

        }).fail(function () {

            alert("erro na conexão");

        });

   });




public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public static List<UserConnection> usersConnect = new List<UserConnection>();


    public void SendOnline(string id, string mensagem)
```

{

```
    var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();



       context.Clients.All.updateStatus(id, mensagem);


}


    public void SendQuestionario(int id, string message, string userNameTo)
    {

        UserConnection connect = usersConnect.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionID == userNameTo);

        if (connect != null)
        {     
            Clients.User(connect.UserName).addNewMessageToPageQuestionario(id, message);

        }        
    }



    public override Task OnConnected()
    {

        string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        string id = Context.User.Identity.GetUserId();

        if (!usersConnect.Exists(x => x.UserName == name))
        {
            usersConnect.Add(new UserConnection { ConnectionID = id, UserName = name });
        }

        return base.OnConnected();
    }
```

Comment: show more code... for example chatHub

Comment: Hello Testar, I add code for chatHub. Whats wrong when I use global start connect?

Comment: How do you call SendQuestionario ... show all code

Comment: It is in the code above where it says "In partial view:"

            window.chat.server.sendQuestionario(id, ($("#resposta_" + id).val()), nome);

Comment: what`s wrong in my code?